# GWT Layout issue

Tags: gwt, gxt

I wrote below code, I could not set the panel to the rightmost side of the container. I want control in moving the panel all the sides, like east, west, north and south.

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    Viewport viewport = new Viewport();
    viewport.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    viewport.add(createContainer());
    RootPanel.get().add(viewport);
}

private Widget createContainer() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LayoutContainer container = new LayoutContainer();
    container.setLayout`enter code here`(new BorderLayout());
    ContentPanel panel = new ContentPanel(new FitLayout());
    panel.setHeading("The Legend");
    BorderLayoutData westData = new BorderLayoutData(LayoutRegion.WEST, 250);
    westData.setSplit(true);
    westData.setCollapsible(true);
    westData.setMargins(new Margins(0, 3, 0, 0));
    container.add(panel, westData);
    return container;
}
```

Can someone help?

Comment: "rightmost side" and `LayoutRegion.WEST` ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your are using GXT. This is a very important information because GXT layout uses other classes than native GWT layout.

Take a look a the Sencha Showcase:

http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:borderlayout

The BorderLayout example shows how to create a border layout.

First create a BorderLayoutContainer:

```
final BorderLayoutContainer con = new BorderLayoutContainer();
con.setBorders(true);
```

Then create panels for the areas you like to have:

```
ContentPanel north = new ContentPanel();
ContentPanel west = new ContentPanel();
ContentPanel center = new ContentPanel();
center.setHeadingText("BorderLayout Example");

center.setResize(false);
center.add(new Label("center"));
 
ContentPanel east = new ContentPanel();
ContentPanel south = new ContentPanel();
```

After creating the ContentPanels define the BorderLAyoutData for each ContentPanel:

```
BorderLayoutData northData = new BorderLayoutData(100);
northData.setMargins(new Margins(5));
northData.setCollapsible(true);
northData.setSplit(true);
 
BorderLayoutData westData = new BorderLayoutData(150);
westData.setCollapsible(true);
westData.setSplit(true);
westData.setCollapseMini(true);
westData.setMargins(new Margins(0, 5, 0, 5));
 
MarginData centerData = new MarginData();
BorderLayoutData eastData = new BorderLayoutData(150);
eastData.setMargins(new Margins(0, 5, 0, 5));
eastData.setCollapsible(true);
eastData.setSplit(true);

BorderLayoutData southData = new BorderLayoutData(100);
southData.setMargins(new Margins(5));
southData.setCollapsible(true);
southData.setCollapseMini(true);
```

After you have defined the layouts, just add your widgets to the BorderLAyoutContainer:

```
con.setNorthWidget(north, northData);
con.setWestWidget(west, westData);
con.setCenterWidget(center, centerData);
con.setEastWidget(east, eastData);
con.setSouthWidget(south, southData);
```

Finally, add the BorderLAyoutContainer to the viewPort:

```
viewport.add(con);
```

To put your widget on the right most side, use:

```
con.setEastWidget(widget, eastData);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Nice writeup on this, but it looks like you are using GXT 3, while the code in the question is using GXT 2.

Comment: yep, you are right, that's GXT 3. Did not thought, that someone would start with GXT 2. And there were no hint, which version is used.

Comment: Agreed, new projects don't make sense to start in GXT 2. I can only tell because several classes in the code only exist in 2, not in 3.

Comment: I stopped using GXT 2.2.x with the first beta of GXT 3.

Comment: I stopped using GXT 2 when I joined Sencha to started writing GXT 3 ;).

Comment: Thank you very much for above explanation.I am trying to create layouts with GXT only.Can we get the layout requirement what we are talking above onlyby using GXT and GWT API.

Comment: Problem in using Sencha is,its licensed version which is not a open source I think,correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @user3082927 You are using GXT 2 in your question, while the answer here is using GXT 3. Both are under the same license, either a commercial one, or GPLv3, whichever you prefer. The only difference is that the answer is using a much newer version.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing this issue as whenever i am trying to collapse the north then that space is NOT being occupied by the South and neither vice versa is happening. I want that whenever we are collapsing the contentPanel (north or south), its space should be occupied by the other Panels.

I am using gxt 3.0.1 in my project.

For gxt 2.x it can be done with the FitLayout() and by setting the layout but in the GXT 3.0.1 the API is different. I am not able to use the FitLayout().

Any new Ideas guys.